# Stub property setter with Rhino.Mocks to execute an action when called?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

This can be done with methods as follows:

```
myStub.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod()).WhenCalled(x => do something);
```

Is there any way the same thing can be done when a property setter is called?

Comment: Jay, did you ever find an AAA solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

The following will work:

```
Expect.Call(myStub.MyProperty).WhenCalled(p => Console.WriteLine("Called")).Return("Test result");
```

Please note that this only works if your properties (`MyProperty` in this case) is declared virtual.

Comment: Thanks, Pieter. What else might I need to do to get this working? I always use the AAA syntax, so I have no experience with record/replay, if that is what this is. When I try it this way I get an `InvalidOperationException` "This action is invalid when the mock object is in replay state." Also, do I set a return value for what is essentially a `void` method (property setter)?

Comment: Yes. What you do is the following: 1. record what you expect (like the answer) 2. call `mocks.ReplayAll()` where mocks is an instance of `MockRepository` 3. perform your tests 4. call `mocks.VerifyAll()`. The last will then `throw` when one or more of the expectations have not been met. If you omit the last call, it won't check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Visual Studio handy, but I am sure something along these lines should work:

```
myStub.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty = null).WhenCalled(x => do something);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried but it did not work, even after adding .IgnoreArguments().  It compiles and runs fine but the WhenCalled expression is never invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Put the mock back into "record" mode and use the old record/playback semantics to set the expectation for the property setter:

```
stub.BackToRecord();
Expect.Call(stub.SomeProperty).SetPropertyAndIgnoreArgument().WhenCalled(p => ...do something...);
stub.Replay();
```

Answer (score 1):

So Pieter and Patrick already gave the correct answer, but if you like to use *out of the box* a more complete example would maybe help. So here it is:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var fakedInterface = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISite>();

    // Stub property setter and call own lambda when invoked.
    fakedInterface.BackToRecord();
    Expect.Call(fakedInterface.Name).SetPropertyAndIgnoreArgument().WhenCalled(a =>
    {
        Assert.That(a.Arguments.Length, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(a.Arguments[0], Is.EqualTo("abc"));

        // Stub property getter with provided value.
        fakedInterface.Stub(x => x.Name).Return((String)a.Arguments[0]);
    });
    fakedInterface.Replay();

    // Set the property (and let our above lambda be invoked)
    fakedInterface.Name = "abc";

    // Get the property (the value that was freshly stubbed within the lamba.
    var result = fakedInterface.Name;
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("abc"));
}
```

The next trick in this example is, that the return value will be stubbed within the lambda, so that you are able to invoke/test anything you like in the setter and in the next step you're able to receive this value through the normal property getter.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but all the answers were a bit unclear.
Since then Ayende has placed a section dealing with this issue with old and new constructs which I thought might be helpful if I find this again.

[Rhino Mocks 3.5](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#PropertySettersExplicitExpectationAPI).

> Two constructs for expecting settings of properties have been added.
>   It has been possible with Rhino.Mocks before, however there has been
>   no expressive construct in the fluent interface syntax.
>
> A property setting expectation with a certain value is specified like
>   this:
>
> Expect.Call(mockedCustomer.Name).SetPropertyWithArguments("Ayende");
>
> For testing the interaction only, a property setting expectation
>   without a specified value is done this way:
>
> Expect.Call(mockedCustomer.Name).SetPropertyAndIgnoreArguments();
>
> Those new constructs are equal to:
>
> using(mocks.Record()) { mockedCustomer.Name = "Ayende"; // setup an
>   expectation for setting a specific argument.
>
> LastCall.IgnoreArguments(); //We can ignore arguments to this
>   expectation, with gives us expectation of setting the
>   property,regardless of the actual value. }